# How to restart 1000's of pods at a time

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

We are having 1000's of pods running for our application. Due to some reason we need to restart 100's of pods.

Is there any way we can do it in kubernetes using kubectl or any other tool. Please advice. It should be pure pod restart.

Comment: What is `pure pod restart` ?

Comment: if its in a specific namespace then via kubectl delete po --all, you can do it, else you have to write a script

Comment: what is the reason to restart the pods?

Comment: We are having 1000's  ...we need to restart 100's   <-- is it a typo, or you need to restart only subset? or all of them? Do these pods have some unique selectors?

Answer (score 2):

One way

```
kubectl scale deploymennt <your-deployment-goes-here> --replicas=0
```

and then

```
kubectl scale deploymennt <your-deployment-goes-here> --replicas=1000
```

Another way:

Write a script that:

1. will acquire a list of all active pods that belong to specific deployment
2. issue kubectl delete pod  in a loop

Yet another way (works if your pods belong to a dedicated namespace 'foo'):

```
kubectl delete --all pods --namespace=foo
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the pods belong to a specific namespace, you can delete them all with
`kubectl delete pods --all --namespace=foo` to recreate them (this may cause downtime).

If all the pods are controlled by the same deployment, you can trigger a rolling restart with `kubectl rollout restart deployment/my-deployment-name.` †

Editing some deployment trivial value will also trigger a [Rolling Update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) (possible no downtime) for all controlled pods (e.g., changing the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` from `30` to `31`).

If the pods are from multiple different deployments, here is a bash script that ["refreshes" all pods in all deployments by namespace.](https://gist.github.com/jmound/ff6fa539385d1a057c82fa9fa739492e)

*† `rollout restart` is only available on kubernetes [v1.15+](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#cli-improvements)*

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion makes sense. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a selector. Note that this is deleting the pods so you'll want to be sure they are running with a higher level construct like a deployment. And be sure your selector doesn't match pods you don't want to touch.

```
kubectl delete pods -l name=myLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart all deployments in a cluster (multiple namespaces)

```
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces | tail +2 | awk '{ cmd=sprintf("kubectl rollout restart deployment -n %s %s", $1, $2) ; system(cmd) }'
```